# How to debug step by step managed code with MDbgEngine

Tags: c#, debugging, mdbg

Assuming that I have simple C# console application (code below).
I want to debug it step by step using mdbg manager wrapper.

```
using System;

namespace TestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            Console.WriteLine("2");
            Console.WriteLine("3");
            Console.WriteLine("4");
            Console.WriteLine("5");
        }
    }
}
```

How to use MDbgEngine to debug this code step by step?

```
[MTAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var debugger = new MDbgEngine();
    debugger.Options.CreateProcessWithNewConsole = true;
    debugger.Options.StopOnException = true;

    var process = debugger.CreateProcess("TestApplication.exe", "", DebugModeFlag.Debug, null);
    process.Go();

    //HOW TO GO STEP BY STEP TROUGH THE TestApplication?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to subscribe to `process.PostDebugEvent` event, Hopefully debugger will stop at very beginning of your application or you can put breakpoint in the location you want using `process.Breakpoints.CreateBreakpoint()`

```
process.PostDebugEvent += (ss, ee) => {
    if (ee.CallbackType == ManagedCallbackType.OnBreakpoint)
    {
        // here do what you want and then you can
        // process.StepInto, StepOver, or StepOut to move from here
    }
};
```